# Inheriting class with private variables, and getters/setters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I do program that lets you calculate work (decorating), it uses quite complex data structure, so have decided to use private variables (in classes) for better code management. I needed 1 class in multiple use cases so I made simple model that I will extend based on specific usage, but I ran into problem. The class I need to extend uses also getters/setters and private variables, but it seems like those are not inheritable.

### Code snippets

#### General model

```js
class Surface {
  #id;
  #name;
  #x;
  #y;
  #value;
  #periphery;
  constructor({ id, name, x, y }) {
    this.#id = id;
    this.#name = name;
    this.#x = x || 0;
    this.#y = y || 0;
    this.calculate();
  }
  calculate() {
    this.#value = this.#x * this.#y;
    this.#periphery = 2 * (this.#x + this.#y);
  }
  // These get/set are not inherited for some reason
  set x(value) {
    this.#x = parseFloat(value || 0);
    this.calculate();
  }
  set y(value) {
    this.#y = parseFloat(value || 0);
    this.calculate();
  }
  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }
  get name() {
    return this.#name;
  }
  get x() {
    return this.#x.toFixedNumber(2);
  }
  get y() {
    return this.#y.toFixedNumber(2);
  }
  get value() {
    return this.#value.toFixedNumber(2);
  }
  get periphery() {
    return this.#periphery.toFixedNumber(2);
  }
  toJSON() {
    return {
      id: this.#id,
      name: this.#name,
      x: this.#x,
      y: this.#y
    };
  }
}
```

#### Specific use

```js
class AtypicalSurfaceWork extends Surface {
  #id;
  #name;
  #x;
  #y;
  #value;
  #periphery;
  #eventSender;
  // Declarations had to be included
  constructor({ id, name, x, y, eventSender }) {
    super({ id, name, x, y });
    this.#eventSender = eventSender;
  }
  set x(value) {
    // Super doesn't work, so I rewrote this part of code
    console.log("Test x");
    this.#x = parseFloat(value || 0);
    this.calculate();
    this.#eventSender.emit("calculate");
  }
  set y(value) {
    // It prints out, so it executes
    console.log("Test y");
    this.#y = parseFloat(value || 0);
    this.calculate();
    this.#eventSender.emit("calculate");
  }
  get surface() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

This is the most simple use case of Surface class, but it doesn't work, so, for now, I stuck to current (I hope it is just temporary) solution to define Surface multiple times.

## Summary of problem

So I want to know if is there an option to inherit getters/setters. This code doesn't throw an error, but every time I try to get some value from AtypicalSurfaceWork it returns undefined and getter does not execute. On the other hand, setters that are defined right in AtypicalSurfaceWork do execute, so I think that getter/setter doesn't inherit. Is there any way to inherit them or I should continue using code with multiple definitions?

Comment: So you want both `AtypicalSurfaceWork`'s and `Surface`'s setters to execute when, for example, you set the `x` property on an instance of `AtypicalSurfaceWork`?

Comment: Yes, I need both setters/getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the setters from `AtypicalSurfaceWork` manually:

```js
const xSuperDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Surface.prototype, "x"),
ySuperDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Surface.prototype, "y");

class AtypicalSurfaceWork extends Surface {
  #id;
  #name;
  #x;
  #y;
  #value;
  #periphery;
  #eventSender;
  // Declarations had to be included
  constructor({ id, name, x, y, eventSender }) {
    super({ id, name, x, y });
    this.#eventSender = eventSender;
  }
  set x(value) {
    console.log("Test x");
    xSuperDescriptor.set.call(this, value);
    this.#eventSender.emit("calculate");
  }
  get x() {
    return xSuperDescriptor.get.call(this);
  }
  set y(value) {
    // It prints out, so it executes
    console.log("Test y");
    ySuperDescriptor.set.call(this, value);
    this.#eventSender.emit("calculate");
  }
  get x() {
    return xSuperDescriptor.get.call(this);
  }
  get surface() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works for setters, but I still need to figure out the getters.

Comment: Same thing, just replace `.set` by `.get`. You can also call them with `.call()`, but don't pass the second parameter.

Comment: I have tried that, but that throws error, that I try to get #x of undefined even when I passed this as argument. And IDE says that argument is unexpected, so I tried both, none of them works. I tried to print the getter, to check its existance (it exists), but the problem is with 'this', if is needed I can provide whole error output.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you for your time and will to help me.